Problemas ejecutar script con crontab
Tengo un script que cuando lo ejecuto en la terminal, va todo bien, pero cuando lo pongo en el cron, se ejecuta solo parte del programa.
El programa se basa en que quiero saber si mi Task Manager está ejecutándose; si lo está, mandar un "si" a un archivo de texto y si no, mandar un "no" y además, ejecutar la acción que lo encenderá. Es un archivo .sh
El script:
#!/bin/bash

export USER="safnwc"

export tm=`ps -fu $USER | fgrep "safnwctm" | grep -v grep`

substring="safnwctm"

DEST_PATH=/home/safnwc

if [[ "$tm" == *"$substring"* ]]

then

    echo "si" >> ${DEST_PATH}/pruebas.txt

else

    echo "no" >> ${DEST_PATH}/pruebas.txt

    SAFNWCTM -r   #ESTO ES EL COMANDO PARA ARRANCAR EL TASK MANAGER Y QUE EL CRON NO EJECUTA

fi

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

¿has probado poniendo la ruta completa del comando SAFNWCTM?  Es decir, algo así como /home/user/carpeta/SAFNWCTM -r o donde sea que se encuentre.

el problema radica, eso creo yo, en que cuando lo ejecutas desde la línea de comandos, tienes un entorno predefinido que no lo está cuando lo ejecutas desde cron. Yo probaría a hacer un comando 'set' y tratar de incluir las variables de entorno básicas para que tu script funcione. Un saludo.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Hay de dos sopas:

Elige la ruta completa del programa SAFNWCTM, ya que puede que este no haya sido encontrado desde dentro de tu script porque la variable PATH de tu script no contiene la carpeta donde está guardado

...
    echo "no" >> ${DEST_PATH}/pruebas.txt
    /ruta/completa/a/SAFNWCTM -r
fi
...


Define la variable PATH dentro de tu script, así que tu programa pueda buscar al programa SAFNWCTM:

export PATH=$PATH:/carpeta/donde/esta/SAFNWCTM
...

Aunque también podrías definir tu PATH en el archivo crontab, pero esto puede repercutir en otros cronjobs.
